# Connect with a Stomp PHP library to Spring websockets (stomp)

Tags: php, spring, websocket, stomp

I've compiled and ran the code from this guide:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

I want to connect using [this](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html) Stomp PHP library to the server which
is started on port 8080 on localhost.

This is the code which I run to connect to Spring server:

```
<?php

// include a library
require_once("Stomp.php");
// make a connection
$con = new Stomp("tcp://localhost:8080");
// connect
$con->connect();

// send a message to the queue
$con->send("/hello", "test");
echo "Sent message with body 'test'\n";
// subscribe to the queue
$con->subscribe("/topic/greetins");
// receive a message from the queue
$msg = $con->readFrame();

// do what you want with the message
if ( $msg != null) {
    echo "Received message with body '$msg->body'\n";
    // mark the message as received in the queue
    $con->ack($msg);
} else {
    echo "Failed to receive a message\n";
}

// disconnect
$con->disconnect();
```

The code will end up in a while loop trying to receive the response
from the server, in file: Stomp.php trying to receive the frame.

The response from the server is next:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 08 Aug 2014 18:11:23 GMT
Connection: close
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick start guide from supertom.com for using PHP Stomp: [http://www.supertom.com/code/activemq-php-stomp-quickstart.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423212512/http://www.supertom.com/code/activemq-php-stomp-quickstart.html) (WebArchive).

When you create a `new Stomp()` you need to pass a TCP socket URL. I'm guessing that your URL looks is an HTTP URL. For example if you're connecting to ActiveMQ then the default URL is `tcp://localhost:61613`.

So you're second line of code would be

`$con = new Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");`